# Fetch record with highest stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables Items, Locations and Stock.

```
Items 
ItemId   ItemName
444      Item-1
555      Item-2
666      Item-3

Locations
LocationId  LocationName
12           Loc1
13           Loc2
14           Loc3
15           Loc4
17           Loc5


Stock
Id          ItemId       LocationId    stock
1           444           12            2
2           444           13            15
3           555           14            20
4           666           15            14
5           666           17            12
```

I Need to fetch 1 record against each item , which has highest stock.
I want Result like this.

```
Result Table
ItemName        LocationName        stock
Item-1            Loc2               15
Item-2            Loc3               20
Item-3            Loc4               14
```

Currently i am using following query.

```
Select I.ItemName,L.LocationName,S.stock from Items I
inner join Stock S on 
I.ItemId = S.ItemId
inner join Locations L on 
S.LocationId = L.LocationId
```

Comment: whats your DBMS?

Comment: Nice complete question, but it doesn't exactly demonstrate much background research before posting.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI-SQL-98 you would first find out the max stock levels on each item, from the stock table, then join back on itself to find the info in the whole row.  From there it's the normal case of joining to translate IDs into Names, etc.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT itemId, MAX(stock) AS stock FROM stock GROUP BY itemId
)
  max_stock
INNER JOIN
  stock
    ON  stock.itemId = max_stock.itemId
    AND stock.stock  = max_stack.stock
INNER JOIN
  locations
    ON locations.LocationId = stock.LocationId
INNER JOIN
  Items
    ON items.ItemId = stock.ItemId
```

In ANSI-SQL-2003 you get windowed functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()`...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    stock.*,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itemId
                     ORDER BY stock DESC
                )
                   AS stock_level_rank
  FROM
    stock
)
  ranked_stock
INNER JOIN
  locations
    ON locations.LocationId = ranked_stock.LocationId
INNER JOIN
  Items
    ON items.ItemId = ranked_stock.ItemId
WHERE
  ranked_stock.stock_level_rank = 1
```

A feature of `RANK()` is that more than one row can be tied for first place.  So you don't always get one row per item.  But then, if two locations have exactly the same stock levels, shouldn't they both be returned?  It depends on your requirements.

If you ***must*** have just one row, it's best to then choose additional columns / expression to order by to deterministically return the same result each time.

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemId
                           ORDER BY stock DESC,
                                    id DESC
                )
                   AS stock_level_rank
```

In this case having a higher `id` makes a row more "preferential" to be the one selected in the case of a tie.  That makes no sense ***really***, but at least you always get the same result for the same input.

Comment: Are you sure stock_level_rank is available in the query?

Comment: @Paparazzi Have I made a typo or something?  The inline-view / sub-query named `ranked_stock` ***should*** indeed expose a column named `stock_level_rank` for the outer-query to be able to filter by.  Just the same way as your CTE exposes a column named `rn`...  I can't *see* a mistake right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(  select itemID, locationID, stock  
        , row_number() over (partition by itemID order by stock desc) as rn 
   from stock  
)  
select * 
from cte 
join items i 
  on i.itemID = cte.itemID  
 and cte.rn = 1  
join locations l 
  on l.LocationId = cte.LocationId
```

Comment: Why `ROW_NUMBER()` rather than `RANK()`?  What are the differences and consequences of either choice?

Comment: @MatBailie I don't think it would make a difference here.

Comment: You don't think two locations / stores / whatever, will ***ever*** have the same stock levels of the same item? ;)

Comment: @MatBailie "I Need to fetch 1 record against each item."   If you think RANK() works better here then have at it.

Comment: I do, and I did, and I explained the differences.  You obviously know what you're doing, so I'm going to assume you don't actually believe that "What the customer initially asks for is actually what the customer really wants".

Comment: @MatBailie Does the ; break anything?  You have a posted answer.

Comment: @MatBailie OK removed